# How to Write c# script for creating msi package in visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, windows-installer

i know that wix installer can be used to create msi package in visual studio but in my case i have a wpf form where the user can select the path of the source file(the file that is going to be deployed) and the output path (Msi package is created here) .When the user click  create msi button then the script runs and creates the msi package in the selected output path.

I came to know that using wix# we can write script but i don't know how to run the script from wpf application.

Comment: wix has also its own ui components... http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i want to select the file from wpf form and then create msi for that file@FlorianSchmidinger

Comment: oh i think i got that wrong... so you created a tool that should eat .wixproj files and compile them?

Comment: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/building_wix.html ...

Comment: yes i have created a wpf application.For example i have selected installme.txt file then the application will create installer for installme.txt file. @FlorianSchmidinger

Comment: Once you have the .wxs (wix file) created, then first you need to run the candle.exe (which comes with the WIX install) on the .wxs file. The output of candle.exe is a .wixobj file. Then you need to run light.exe on the .wixobj file and you will get your MSI.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/candle.html
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html